# Proof of $\mathbb E[\exp( \lambda XY)]=\mathbb E[\exp( \lambda^2 X^2)/2]$, where $X,Y$ are independent standard normal random variables

Tags: probability-theory

I have a heuristic proof of the fact $\mathbb E[\exp( \lambda XY)]=\mathbb E[\exp( \lambda^2 X^2)/2]$,where $X,Y$ are independent standard normal random variables as follows:

Using the fact that $\mathbb E[\exp( \lambda Z)]=\exp(\lambda^2/2)$, where $Z$ is standard normal.

By conditioning, we have 
$\mathbb E[\exp( \lambda XY)]=\mathbb E (\mathbb E[\exp( \lambda XY)\mid X])$, at this point, one may *treat $X$ as a constant* (heuristically I take $\mathbb E[\exp( \lambda XY)\mid X]=\exp(\lambda^2 X^2/2) $, but is it true and why is it true? ) and use the formula above to get $E[\exp( \lambda^2 X^2)/2]$.

But how to make this argument formal and rigorous? Any other proof will also be appreciated!

Comment: Which part of this argument is not formal or rigorous? We are using the law of total expectation.

Comment: @StubbornAtom  the part that treats X as a constant

Comment: @StubbornAtom See my third paragraph, in ptc the sentence in the parenthesis. I don't see how to use the fact in the second paragraph in a straight way.

Comment: Your heuristic argument doesn't quite cut it because it does not make use of the fact that $X$ and $Y$ are independent, which is necessary

Comment: @user159517 you're right, I also just realized that. But how to prove it rigorously, using any method?

Comment: If it helps, consider that

$E[e^{\lambda XY}\mid X=x]=E[e^{\lambda x Y}\mid X=x]=E[e^{\lambda xY}]=e^{\lambda ^2x^2/2}$, so $E[e^{\lambda XY}\mid X]=e^{\lambda ^2X^2/2}$.

Comment: Maybe you can do \begin{align}\mathbb E[\exp( \lambda XY)\mid X] &= \mathbb E\left[\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(\lambda X Y)^n}{n!} \mid X\right] = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (\lambda X)^n \mathbb E\left[ \frac{Y^n}{n!} \mid X \right] = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(\lambda X)^n}{n!}\mathbb E\left[ Y^n \mid X \right] \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(\lambda X)^n}{n!}\mathbb E\left[ Y^n\right] = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(\lambda X)^n}{n!}\mathbb E\left[ X^n\right]  \end{align} and then use the explicit formula for the moments to compare $\mathbb E[X^n]^2$ with $\mathbb E[X^{2n}]$ to conclude

Comment: @user159517 Thanks, but note that this argument doesn't actually need conditioning at all. Just do the Taylor expansion of LHS at the beginning

Comment: @NoOne I know but I thought it was neater this way. Maybe I'll have time later to check if it actually works (I guess it should if the claim is true)

Comment: @StubbornAtom This is still not very formal to me, at least it's not clear where the independence of X and Y is used

Comment: @NoOne just out of curiosity, what use does this identity have?

Comment: @NoOne Independence of X and Y was used to go from E(Y^n|X) to EY.

Comment: @Glassjawed: Or, more generally, from the conditional expectation to the unconditional expectation. People don't see this because of the common deficient notation; it is extremely clear once conditional expectation is made precise as in my answer. Too bad it isn't more commonly done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write 
$$\begin{align}
E(\exp(\lambda XY)) &= \int \exp(\lambda xy)dP_{(X,Y)}(x,y) \tag 1 \\
&= \int \int \exp(\lambda xy)dP_X(x) dP_Y(y) \tag 2\\
&= \int \left(\int \exp(\lambda xy)dP_Y(y)\right) dP_X(x) \tag 3\\
&= \int E(\exp(\lambda xY)) dP_X(x)\\
&= \int \exp( \lambda^2 x^2)/2\; dP_X(x)\\
&= E(\exp( \lambda^2 X^2)/2)
\end{align}$$

$(1)$: law of the unconscious statistician
$(2)$: independence of $X$ and $Y$
$(3)$: Tonelli's theorem

Answer (score 1):

There is not even a need for integrals. One can perfectly rigorously manipulate expectations as long as one **specifies** the 'space' over which the expectation is taken. And this algebraic proof applies equally to all random variables, whether discrete or continuous or mixed. In particular,$\def\ee{\mathbb{E}}$ let $\ee_{Y|X}(f(X,Y))$ denote the expectation of $f(X,Y)$ over the conditional space of $Y$ given $X$ (i.e. treating $X$ as constant in evaluating the expectation). Similarly for more variables.

Firstly, note that if $Y$ is independent of $X$ then $\ee_{Y|X}(f(X,Y)) = \ee_Y(f(X,Y))$. If $X,Y$ are not independent this may not hold, for example if $X = Y$ then $\ee_{Y|X}(X-Y) = 0$ whereas $\ee_Y(X-Y) = X-\ee_Y(Y)$.

Secondly, the law of total expectation can be used as an axiom, namely that for any random variables $X,Y,...$ we have $\ee_{X,Y,...}(f(X,Y,...)) = \ee_X(\ee_{Y,...|X}(f(X,Y,...)))$.

With this, it is trivial to prove the desired result purely algebraically.

For any independent $X,Y \sim N(0,1)$, we have $\ee_{X,Y}(\exp(λXY))$ $= \ee_X(\ee_{Y|X}(\exp(λXY)))$ $= \ee_X(\ee_Y(\exp(λXY)))$ $= \ee_X(\exp((λX)^2/2))$.

Your result is wrong because you put the brackets in the wrong place.